# Can't start up NetworkManager in Arch Linux: symbol loolkup error: /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4: undefined symbol: libssh2_session_set_read_timeout

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, networkmanager, software-updates, snapper

Last thursday I updated my Arch Linux installtion and when I rebooted on Friday my system had multiple problems. I'm new to the Arch Linux (or Linux in general) community and don't know what things I can try to make it work again.

Most applications as well as the network won't start. I use KDE Plasma as GUI manager.
When I click on the menu I get:

```
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.kickoff/contents/ui/Kickoff.qml:19:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "org.kde.plasma.private.kicker": Cannot load library /usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/plasma/private/kicker/libkickerplugin.so: (libicui18n.so.73: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

When I inspect the plugin with `pacman -Qo /usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/plasma/private/kicker/libkickerplugin.so` I get:
`pacman: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4: undefined symbol: libssh2_session_set_read_timeout`

Following the [forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=240906) I checked my installtion with `ls -l /usr/lib/libssh*`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Nov  1  2022 /usr/lib/libssh2.so -> libssh2.so.1.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Nov  1  2022 /usr/lib/libssh2.so.1 -> libssh2.so.1.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 268552 Nov  1  2022 /usr/lib/libssh2.so.1.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     11 May  4 14:43 /usr/lib/libssh.so -> libssh.so.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 May  4 14:43 /usr/lib/libssh.so.4 -> libssh.so.4.9.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 445776 May  4 14:43 /usr/lib/libssh.so.4.9.5
```

(Which is equal to what a colleague has)

When checking the status with `sudo systenctl status NetworkManager.service` I get this output:

```
× NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-07-28 09:17:10 CEST; 44min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
    Process: 1261 ExecStart=/usr/bin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=exited, status=127)
   Main PID: 1261 (code=exited, status=127)
        CPU: 9ms

Jul 28 09:17:10 brunb513 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 28 09:17:10 brunb513 systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Jul 28 09:17:10 brunb513 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 28 09:17:10 brunb513 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 28 09:17:10 brunb513 systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
Jul 28 09:17:10 brunb513 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
```

From `journalctl -xeu NetworkManager.service` I get:

```
░░ Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 100.
Jul 28 09:17:10 brunb513 NetworkManager[1068]: /usr/bin/NetworkManager: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4: undefined symbol: libssh2_session_set_read_timeout
Jul 28 09:17:10 brunb513 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit NetworkManager.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 127.
Jul 28 09:17:10 brunb513 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ The unit NetworkManager.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 28 09:17:10 brunb513 systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 100 and the job result is failed.
Jul 28 09:17:10 brunb513 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
...
```

So I assume there is a problem with the `libcurl`

I tried setting up the network to no avail:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s13f0u2u1c2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:ce:c8:92:e9:ca brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:21:4a:b1:06:70 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br-37febc211f8d: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:88:b3:02:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:6b:02:be:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

With `ip link set <Network> up` but it did nothing.

I tried using `snapper` to reset to a version earlier than the updates:

```
1821  | single |       | Mon 24 Jul 2023 11:00:00 AM CEST | root | timeline | timeline                                                                 |              
1828  | single |       | Thu 27 Jul 2023 09:00:00 AM CEST | root | timeline | timeline                                                                 |              
1836  | pre    |       | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:17:44 PM CEST | root | number   | /usr/lib/packagekitd                                                     |              
1837  | post   |  1836 | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:17:46 PM CEST | root | number   | chromium cmake cppdap dolphin plasma-workspace                           |              
1838  | pre    |       | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:18:19 PM CEST | root | number   | /usr/lib/packagekitd                                                     |              
1839  | post   |  1838 | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:18:19 PM CEST | root | number   | kate kinfocenter kmenuedit konsole plasma-systemmonitor qt5-tools specta |              
1840  | pre    |       | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:18:34 PM CEST | root | number   | /usr/lib/packagekitd                                                     |              
1841  | post   |  1840 | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:18:39 PM CEST | root | number   | fwupd jdk17-openjdk jre17-openjdk jre17-openjdk-headless yakuake         |              
1842  | pre    |       | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:20:44 PM CEST | root | number   | /usr/lib/packagekitd                                                     |              
1843  | post   |  1842 | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:20:45 PM CEST | root | number   | discover kdeplasma-addons plasma-desktop plasma-disks plasma-firewall    |              
1844  | pre    |       | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:21:04 PM CEST | root | number   | /usr/lib/packagekitd                                                     |              
1845  | post   |  1844 | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:21:04 PM CEST | root | number   | bluedevil plasma-nm plasma-pa plasma-vault                               |              
1846  | pre    |       | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:21:32 PM CEST | root | number   | /usr/lib/packagekitd                                                     |              
1847  | post   |  1846 | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:21:32 PM CEST | root | number   | ark                                                                      |              
1848  | pre    |       | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:21:46 PM CEST | root | number   | /usr/lib/packagekitd                                                     |              
1849  | post   |  1848 | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:21:50 PM CEST | root | number   | alsa-card-profiles plasma-welcome systemsettings                         |              
1850  | pre    |       | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:22:15 PM CEST | root | number   | /usr/lib/packagekitd                                                     |              
1851  | post   |  1850 | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:22:15 PM CEST | root | number   | xdg-desktop-portal-kde xfsprogs xkeyboard-config xorg-server xorg-server |              
1852  | pre    |       | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:22:25 PM CEST | root | number   | /usr/lib/packagekitd                                                     |              
1853  | post   |  1852 | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:22:29 PM CEST | root | number   | archlinux-appstream-data archlinux-keyring                               |              
1854  | pre    |       | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:22:58 PM CEST | root | number   | /usr/lib/packagekitd                                                     |              
1855  | post   |  1854 | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:23:07 PM CEST | root | number   | at-spi2-core attica autorandr baloo baloo-widgets bison bluez bluez-libs |              
1856  | pre    |       | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:23:23 PM CEST | root | number   | /usr/lib/packagekitd                                                     |              
1857  | post   |  1856 | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:23:23 PM CEST | root | number   | duktape enchant exiv2 fakeroot flac frameworkintegration freetype2 fuse- |              
1858  | pre    |       | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:24:55 PM CEST | root | number   | /usr/lib/packagekitd                                                     |              
1859  | post   |  1858 | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:24:59 PM CEST | root | number   | ca-certificates-mozilla curl cython docker drkonqi gcab gcc gcc-libs gdb |              
1860  | pre    |       | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:26:05 PM CEST | root | number   | /usr/lib/packagekitd                                                     |              
1861  | post   |  1860 | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:26:06 PM CEST | root | number   | upower util-linux util-linux-libs vulkan-icd-loader vulkan-intel vulkan- |              
1862  | pre    |       | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:26:26 PM CEST | root | number   | /usr/lib/packagekitd                                                     |              
1863  | post   |  1862 | Thu 27 Jul 2023 04:26:27 PM CEST | root | number   | taglib talloc tar tdb tevent threadweaver tracker3                       |              
1865  | single |       | Fri 28 Jul 2023 09:00:00 AM CEST | root | timeline | timeline                                                                 |              
1879  | single |       | Sat 29 Jul 2023 12:00:00 AM CEST | root | timeline | timeline                                                                 |              
1881  | single |       | Sat 29 Jul 2023 02:00:00 AM CEST | root | timeline | timeline                                                                 |              
1882  | single |       | Sun 30 Jul 2023 01:51:11 AM CEST | root | timeline | timeline                                                                 |              
1883  | single |       | Tue 01 Aug 2023 01:00:00 PM CEST | root | timeline | timeline                                                                 |              
1884  | single |       | Thu 03 Aug 2023 10:00:00 AM CEST | root | timeline | timeline                                                                 |              
1885  | single |       | Thu 03 Aug 2023 11:00:00 AM CEST | root | timeline | timeline                                                                 |              
1886  | single |       | Thu 03 Aug 2023 12:00:00 PM CEST | root | timeline | timeline                                                                 |              
1887  | single |       | Thu 03 Aug 2023 01:00:00 PM CEST | root | timeline | timeline                                                                 |              
1888  | single |       | Thu 03 Aug 2023 02:00:00 PM CEST | root | timeline | timeline                                                                 |              
1889  | single |       | Thu 03 Aug 2023 03:00:00 PM CEST | root | timeline | timeline                                                                 |              
1890  | single |       | Sat 05 Aug 2023 02:47:14 PM CEST | root |          | Rollback before restoring to 1828                                        |              
1891  | single |       | Sat 05 Aug 2023 02:50:08 PM CEST | root | number   | rollback backup                                                          | important=yes
1892  | single |       | Sat 05 Aug 2023 02:50:08 PM CEST | root | number   | writable copy of #1828                                                   |              
1893  | single |       | Sat 05 Aug 2023 02:56:19 PM CEST | root | number   | rollback backup of #1892                                                 | important=yes
1894+ | single |       | Sat 05 Aug 2023 02:56:19 PM CEST | root |          | writable copy of #1828                                                   |              
1895  | single |       | Sat 05 Aug 2023 03:00:00 PM CEST | root | timeline | timeline                                                                 |
```

With `sudo snapper rollback 1828` but it did not help.

What more can I try? Please be as detailed as possible or provide links as I'm new to this.

I can't create an Arch Linux Forum user as I cannot solve the Captcha with my broken system...

Answer (score 0):

hope wasn't too late. I meet same error as you

> /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4: undefined symbol:
> libssh2_session_set_read_timeout

It turns out that [they add a new tag libssh2_session_set_timeout
in high version of libssh2](https://libssh2.org/libssh2_session_set_timeout.html)

I guess you accidentally updated your curl which relied on high version of libssh2 that has the tag, and the libssh2 in your system is still the old version.

What I did is I compiled a new [libssh2](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/releases) in a new dir, backuped the old libssh2 in my system and moved newly compiled libssh2 into /usr/lib (2 lib files, libssh2.so.1 libssh2.so.1.0.1), and it solved my problem.